# Where is the bottom of the stack in an Intel 8086 cpu?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers, callstack

Assume for example that `SS=0000h` and the size of the stack is 256 bytes.

Where is the stack pointer register (`SP`) initially pointing at?
I guess it is 0100h.

And where is the bottom of the stack?
0100h or 00FFh?

Comment: The "top" position of the stack is typically not 0, so if the stack size is 256 bytes, the stack is not the address range 0...0xFF but for example 0x8000...0x80FF. This is not only the case for x86 CPUs, but for any other CPU type that allows the stack to be placed anywhere in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In x86, the stack pointer points to the most recently pushed item, and grows downwards.

With an empty stack, the SP would therefore be at `0100h`. When a `push` is done, the SP will first be decremented by 2, then the data will be stored at that new address, `00FEh`, occupying the two bottom-most (highest address) bytes of the stack.

The stack is empty when the top of the stack is also the bottom of the stack, so the bottom of the stack is `0100h`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!